# Release filter for Grid

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I have features Rally.ui.grid.Grid and I want to add filter for release like on the Portfolio Item page. How I can do it?
It's my grid.

```
this._myGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        title: 'Feature Scoring Grid',
        store: myStore,
        enableEditing: true,
        enableRanking: true,
        columnCfgs: [
            {
                dataIndex: 'DragAndDropRank',
                maxWidth: 50
            },
            { // override ID and Name - no changes on these allowed in this grid
                text: 'Portfolio ID',
                dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                flex: 1,
                xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate') // make the ID a live link
            },
            {
                text: "Name",
                dataIndex: "Name",
                flex: 2
            },
            {
                text: "Release",
                dataIndex: "Release",
                flex: 3
            },
            "TimeValue", 'OERR', 'UserValue', 'jobSize', // use native Ext formatting - allows cell edits & got rid of errors
            { // override score so that the user can't edit it
                text: "Score",
                dataIndex: 'Score'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Sorting for release doesn't work correctly to and I don't understand how to fix it.
I didn't find any examples with when the release filter works correctly for for features.

Answer (score 1):

You may see an example of features filtered by Releases in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/features-by-release-with-stories).

This apps extends [Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp)

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'release',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select a Release:',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },
```

and a wsapi store of PI/Features is filtered by release:

```
_makeStore: function(){
         Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
            fetch: ['FormattedID','Name'],
            pageSize: 100,
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
            listeners: {
                load: this._onDataLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        }); 
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for example.
But filter does not work for me... I don't know the reason.
App that you shared also doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by the app doesn't work - it does not filter by Release or some other problem? I captured a short video of using that app here: http://screencast.com/t/2co1Tgxehn  The code is copied directly from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmusaelian-rally/features-by-release-with-stories/master/deploy/App.html

Comment: After applying the filter, WsapiDataStore doesn't return features.
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null".

I just added your code into Rally, the same way.

Comment: Are you on a custom page that is scoped to Release?

Comment: @nickm can we do same group by project ?